# Investment on agriculture

Tags: investment

Asalaam Alaikum, I want to ask about an agricultural investment I was introduced to. All I need to do is put like $5,000 and I will be getting $1.000 after every four months. I will not be working there but all I will do is just to invest my money in it. Does this goes along with Sunnah ?  I need to know this before I start.  Jazāk Allāhu Khayran

Comment: This depends on what the contract is, if you are in a partnership then there will be profit sharing on the actual yield, you can not get a fixed return. On the other hand if you own the land and rent it then you may get a fixed return. Either way quarterly $1000 on $5000 is an absurd return on investment, it is likely a scam.